# How to set default value enable in system.xml enabledisable group value magento?

Tags: php, magento

```
Check below xml field to set default value.
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <tabs>
        <facebook translate="label" module="facebook">
            <label>Facebook</label>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
        </facebook>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <facebooksection translate="label" module="facebook">                    
            <label>Facebook</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>100</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>            
            <groups>
                <facebookgroup translate="label">
                    <label>Facebook Details</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>                        
                        <facebook translate="timeline">
                            <label>Facebook</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                            
                        </facebook> 
                      </fields>
                      </facebookgroup>
        .........
```

In this defaut value disable, how can set default value enable?
In this defaut value disable, how can set default value enable?
In this defaut value disable, how can set default value enable?